# use outlet in xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5.0.1

I added property statusText in veiwcontroller

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *statusText;, 

@synthesize statusText;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                             @"%@ кнопка нажата.", title];
    [statusText setText:newText];
```

joined the label and outlet, but when i debug it statusText is nil. Why?

i try some kind ways, but statusTex is nil anyway

Comment: Did you correctly connect the label to its IBOutlet field and the IBAction method to the button?

Comment: when i debug action is worked - action correct connect to button, in h file iboutlet have a point on the left (i ctrl drag the label to h file and add property). in m file i only add code above

Comment: Sometimes XIB changes don't get propagated all the way down to the device.  Try performing a clean (Product > Clean), then run again.

Comment: If you add an NSLog to check the output of 'newText' before setting 'statusText' are you getting the string you want?

Comment: i try clean later, when i debug i saw value of newText before setting 'statusText' , it is correct, but value of 'statusText' in same moment is nil

Comment: Done) example from the book -                       (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.statusText=nil;
}               I made a mistake in the name of the method - viewDidUnLoad instead   viewDidLoad